# Remove CoreGraphics Animation

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

How can I remove an animation using animationDidStop?

I apply the animation

```
let animationTwo = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
animationTwo.delegate = self
animationTwo.fromValue = 0.0
animationTwo.toValue = 1.0
animationTwo.duration = 1.0
animationTwo.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeInEaseOut)
myView.layer.add(animationTwo, forKey: "fade")
```

And then try to remove it

```
func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
    if anim == myView.layer.animation(forKey: "fade") {
        myView.layer.removeAnimation(forKey: "fade")
    }
}
```

However `anim == myView.layer.animation(forKey: "fade")` never resolves to true.

How can I remove the animation when it is complete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CAAnimation` has a property called `isRemovedOnCompletion` which defaults to `true`

This means your animation would be removed from render tree when it is finished. I guess that's why `anim == myView.layer.animation(forKey: "fade")` is not resolving to `true` because it has already been removed.